# Unable to import numpy fork when using Anaconda

Tags: python, git, numpy, github, anaconda

When downloading a numpy fork to my desktop, I try to import the numpy file when running python, but I use Anaconda and it automatically imports numpy version from Anaconda. How do I import the numpy fork over the numpy previously installed?

Comment: show your code first ?

Comment: You have to at the very least build your copy of numpy and add it to the PYTHONPATH.